# ConvertTo not implemented in base TypeConverter

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmapimage

I am trying to convert Bitmap image to byte[] array.

**Code**

```
ImageSourceConverter converter = new ImageSourceConverter();
byte[] data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmapImage, typeof(byte[]));
```

I am getting following error while running this code

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

**Message**

```
ConvertTo not implemented in base TypeConverter.
```

I am getting how to implement **ConvertTo** method. Can someone please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Get a stream from `bitmapImage` and then pass it by `memmoryStream` to byte array.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15460/C-Image-to-Byte-Array-and-Byte-Array-to-Image-Conv

Comment: I have tried this. It works fine. But the problem is, when you have lots of image(100 images) then it create a proble of OutofMemory Exception

Comment: Make sure you dispose each bitmap image and stream before you continue to the next image

Comment: It shouldn't cause exception, if you will dispose images and close streams, like dotMorten said. The problem with ConvertTo method can be caused that it's really unimplemented for bitmapImage type. You can overload this with your own method which uses memoryStream like I've said before.

Comment: I have disposed the stream object. How to dispose Bitmap Image ?

Comment: [Bitmap.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.dispose(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: BitmapImage doesn't have dispose method

Comment: So you don't need to dispose it. Garbage collector will colect this automatically, when needed. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c0cbb4a0-38d8-484b-8c56-9a2ca04392df/how-do-i-dispose-of-image-bitmapimage